How would a non-Euclidean geometry of the universe impact fundamental concepts in physics that rely on notions of orthogonality?
I recently picked up a book on hyperbolic geometry, and while reading it something occurred to me— many concepts fundamental to our modern understanding of physics rely on some notion of geometric orthogonality (take, for example, the fact that light comprises orthogonal electric and magnetic waves), a notion which does not make sense in the context of non-Euclidean geometries. While the geometry of our reality is clearly locally Euclidean (or at least approximately so), there is some evidence to suggest that the overall geometry of the universe may be non-Euclidean.
Suppose that we should find that the geometry of the universe is indeed non-Euclidean. I have two questions:

In what ways would this affect our fundamental understanding of physics? I know what this would mean on a "broader" scale (e.g., for cosmology), but would it impact our current physical theories more generally and fundamentally?

To what degree would these effects be observable? Our everyday observable reality appears to be perfectly Euclidean. Given the uncertainty present in modern measurements, how curved could the universe possibly be on, say, a local scale? How precise would our measurements need to be of these effects need to be in order to observe these effects?



Consider that the universe already isn't Euclidean, it is Minkowskian.

The existence of relativity certainly affects many things... this is due to space being non-Euclidean.

You came more than a hundred years too late.

Orthogonality makes perfect sense in non-Euclidean geometries.

To get the flavor of what such a space is like, the surface of the Earth is a $2$D curved space with a positive curvature. Start at the equator. Walk east  quarter of the way around the world. Turn left $90^o$ and walk north a quarter of the way around the world to the north pole. Turn left $90^o$ and walk north a quarter of the way around the world  back to the start. You have walked a triangle with $3$ right angles.
If you look nearby, things look ordinary. At each vertex, you can draw a pair of perpendicular lines with $4$ right angles like normal. If you look at a larger scale, these are vertices of $4$ triangles with 3 right angles. You can tile the sphere with these triangles.
If you walk smaller triangles, the angle always add up to more than $180^o$, but less than the $270^o$ of the bigger triangle. At scales we are used to walking, you cannot measure the difference from flat space.
Here is a video showing a similar $3$D space with a negative curvature. on-euclidean virtual reality using ray marching. The lengths of the cubes have been set up to the equivalent of a quarter of the way around the world. Again things look normal on a small scale, but you can tile space with pentagonal "cubes" with $5$ right angles.
Gravity is a consequence of curved spacetime. Gravity is very observable. In flat space, objects in motion without external forces move in straight lines at constant velocity. When spacetime is curved, the trajectories bend and accelerate.
On the very largest scales of the universe, galaxies are like molecules in a fluid. The density is uniform as close as we can tell. Spacetime is as close enough to flat that we cannot measure the difference.
On smaller scales, you do see effects of curvature if you get close to a mass. Near the earth, you see a dropped rock accelerate. Planets orbit the sun. In the strong gravity near a black hole, light is noticeably bent and red shifted, which creates strange visual effects. How to Understand the Image of a Black Hole Over long distances, the gentler gravity of a cluster of galaxies can also bend light, causing gravitational lensing.


many concepts fundamental to our modern understanding of physics rely on some notion of geometric orthogonality …, a notion which does not make sense in the context of non-Euclidean geometries

Orthogonality does make sense in non-Euclidean geometries. You may not be able to unambiguously determine the angle between distant vectors in a curved geometry. But locally orthogonality still makes sense.

Suppose that we should find that the geometry of the universe is indeed non-Euclidean

We have already found that. The geometry of the universe is locally Lorentzian. The large scale geometry of the universe is still under investigation.

In what ways would this affect our fundamental understanding of physics?

The impact of this is all of the ways that relativistic physics differs from non-relativistic physics. However, there is also a formulation of Newtonian physics which treats gravity geometrically, meaning that even Newtonian gravity can be described in geometrical terms.

To what degree would these effects be observable?

Very observable. The Experimental Basis of SR describes a wide variety of experiments observing these effects.

Our everyday observable reality appears to be perfectly Euclidean. Given the uncertainty present in modern measurements, how curved could the universe possibly be on, say, a local scale?

There is a big difference between Euclidean and flat. They do not mean the same thing at all. The local Lorentzian geometry of the universe is flat, but decidedly not Euclidean.
The fact that it is Lorentzian and not Euclidean can be seen locally by all of the local experiments described in the link above.
The curvature of the universe is essentially tidal gravity. So any detection of tidal gravitational effects is a detection of the universe’s local curvature.
